# AMDGPU-PRO Driver Installation Failure Centos 7.3

Tags: centos, amd-graphics, proprietary-drivers

Installation fails with 404 Errors downloading required files. I've seen the same problem addressed with older versions of it. It's possible that I am doing something wrong. Sequence of events goes

1. In grub, edit command line, removing blacklist nouveau and appending single at the end.
2. In single user mode use telinit 3.
3. Log in as root.
4. cd to amdgpu-pro* (created from the extraction of amdgpu-pro-16.60-39184.tar)
5. ping www.google.com success
6. run the executable. Output is normal all the way to the point of listing required downloads and asking for confirmation to begin.
7. choosing 'y' to bgin results in a cascade of 404 errors.
8. ping www.google.com success
   Steps are repeatable. Ironically I am replacing a dead NVDIA GTX 970 with an AMD card because I was tired of the driver hassle and many linux users recommend AMD over NVDIA for that and related issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried again this morning. The script downloaded everything without problems. Some sites must have been busy watching football ;-)